# Javascript - make function in object global

Tags: javascript, function, global

Let's say I have an object `obj` with a function `f1` that accept two parameters `a` and `b`. The function is called as follows:

```
obj.f1(a,b);
```

Now I want to make `f1` accessible without calling `obj` as follows:

```
f1(a,b);
```

Is this possible? If so, how may I achieve this?

Edit: If yes, is there a way to make all functions in the object global without knowing the specific functions?

Comment: `const f1 = obj.f1` and then call it later using `f1(a, b)`? this is assuming that `f1` doesn't rely on `this`

Comment: @NickParsons Sounds good. Is there a way to make all functions in the object global without knowing the specific functions?

Comment: yes and no. generally this is not a good idea, and i'm curios why you would want to do that. ... that said, since there is no "true" global, but only `global` and `window` objects dependening on your env, you could just loop over your object and copy all entries of type function into `global` or `window`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While its not the best idea to do this, you can add properties to the global `window` object (if running this in the browser, if you're using node, then you can refer to `global` - here I'm using [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) so this works in both environments), and then call these without needing to prefix `obj`. Adding properties to `window` (ie: globalThis) isn't a good idea usually because you can end up overwriting pre-existing properties on the window. With that being said, here is how you may go about it:

```js
const obj = {x: 1, y: function() {
  console.log("hello");
}}

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
   if(typeof val === "function") 
    globalThis[key] = val; 
});

y();
```

Keep in mind, if your object's methods refer to `this`, then when calling your method the `this` will get bound to the global object (ie: `window`), or, if you're running this in strict mode, then it will be `undefined`.

Here are some examples of some of the caveats mentioned above:

**Modifying pre-existing properties**: The window object has some pre-existing properties. One such property is the `name` property, which JS enforces to be a string. This means that if you have a method called `name` in your object, it will be converted to a string once it gets added to the `window`:

```js
const obj = {x: 1, name: function() {
  console.log("hello");
}}

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
   if(typeof val === "function") 
    globalThis[key] = val; 
});

console.log(typeof name); // string
name(); // Crash: "Uncaught TypeError: name is not a function"
```

**Losing the `this` inside your method**: If your method refers to `this`, then you can expect your method to no longer work, as it loses its `this` binding:

```js
const obj = {x: 1, y: function() {
  console.log(this.x); // undefined (as `this` now refers to window)
}, z:  function() {
  'use strict';
  console.log(this.x); // Crashes, because this is undefined when in strict-mode
}}

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
   if(typeof val === "function") 
    globalThis[key] = val; 
});

y(); // undefined
z(); // "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined"
```

To help rectify the above issues with `this`, you can consider binding your method as you assign it to the window so its context is predefined:

```js
const obj = {x: 1, y: function() {
  console.log(this.x); // this is bound to `obj` (via the .bind() method)
}, z:  function() {
  'use strict';
  console.log(this.x); // this is bound to `obj` (via the .bind() method)
}}

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
   if(typeof val === "function") 
    globalThis[key] = val.bind(obj); 
});

y(); // 1
z(); // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [destructure](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-object-destructuring-spread-operator-rest-parameter/) the properties of an object like this:

```js
const someObject = {
  f1: (a, b) => a + b,
  f2: (a, b) => a * b,
  defaultParams: [1, 1],
}

const {f1, f2, defaultParams} = someObject;

console.log(f1(defaultParams[0], 15) * f2(...defaultParams));
```

Or retrieve the entries from an Object and assign them to a global scope (here `window`, which is [not advisable](https://gist.github.com/hallettj/64478)).

```js
const someObject = {
  f1: (a, b) => a + b,
  f2: (a, b) => a * b,
  defaultParams: [1, 1],
}

Object.entries(someObject).forEach( ([key, entry]) => window[key] = entry );

console.log(f1(defaultParams[0], 15) * f2(...defaultParams));
```

You can create an anonymous scope. In the next snippet `this` should be bound to the Object, so the methods are wrapped using `[function].apply`. Furthermore an alternative way of destructuring is used.

```js
// this syntax creates an anonymous scope
// so f1/f2/defaultParams are *not* window properties
(() => {
  const someObject = {
    b: 42,
    f1(a) { return a + this.b; },
    f2(a) { return a * this.b; },
    defaultParams: [1, 1],
  }
 
  // another way of destructuring ...
  const [f1, f2, defaultParams] = [
    (...params) => someObject.f1.apply(someObject, params),
    (...params) => someObject.f2.apply(someObject, params),
    someObject.defaultParams,
  ];
  
  // or use the shorter *bind* syntax, e.g.
  const f3 = someObject.f1.bind(someObject);

  console.log(f1(defaultParams[0]), f2(2));
  console.log(f3(defaultParams[0]));
  
  // still NOT advisable, but coming to think of it ...
  window.f2FromWithin = someObject.f2.bind(someObject);
  
})();

console.log(f2FromWithin(42));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is using two 'deprecated' commands: `with` and `eval` :)

```
// assuming this is in the node.js
with (obj) {
    for (i in obj) {
        eval('global.'+i+'='+i);
    }
}
```